# Can I create accessors on structs to automatically convert to/from other datatypes?

Tags: c#, struct, accessor

is it possible to do something like the following:

```
struct test
{
   this
   {
      get { /*do something*/ }
      set { /*do something*/ }
   }
}
```

so that if somebody tried to do this,

```
test tt = new test();
string asd = tt; // intercept this and then return something else
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @John Knoeller: updated the question

Comment: Sounds like you want a conversion operator...

Comment: @Shog9: I just want to know if something such as this is possible

Comment: Maybe a little more explanation of what it is you are trying to accomplish. Unless you have a ToString() override or implicit operator in your struct, you won't be able to achieve what I *think* you want with `string asd = tt;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually, what you want to do here is in fact possible within .NET and C#, but you're barking up the wrong tree with regards to syntax. It seems like an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) would be the solution here,

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
   public static implicit operator string(Foo value)
   {
      // Return string that represents the given instance.
   }

   public static implicit operator Foo(string value)
   {
      // Return instance of type Foo for given string value.
   }
}
```

This allows you to assign and return strings (or any other type) to/from objects of your custom type (`Foo` here).

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo = "foobar";
var string = foo; // "foobar"
```

The two implicit conversion operators don't have to be symmetric of course, though it's usually advisable.

Note: There are also [`explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) conversion operators, but I think you're more after implicit operators.

Comment: @sniperX: you must create a new instance of Foo, based on the string.

Comment: Yes, Shog9 is right. If you don't want to expose the constructor directly, there's no problem with just making it private/protected.

Answer (score 2):

You can define [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) conversion operators to and from your custom type.

```
public static implicit operator string(test value)
{
    return "something else";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [MikeP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353632/structs-get-set-accessors/2353657#2353657) you want something like:

```
public static implicit operator Test( string value )
{
    //custom conversion routine
}
```

or

```
public static explicit operator Test( string value )
{
    //custom conversion routine
}
```